# "How to use of angular Material DatePicker with Input tag going hide ?"

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, mat-datepicker

I am working with Angular Material and facing the problem to manage the DatePicker component because it's doing hide input box and because of that the selected date is not coming in the value of Input tag.

```
<mat-form-field>

   <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="Anniversary">

       <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1">
       </mat-datepicker-toggle>

       <mat-datepicker #picker1>
       </mat-datepicker>

</mat-form-field>
```

[Attached Picture of My Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlMjC.png)